# Count of test users created for a facebook app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-test-users

Is there a way to check **count of test users created** for the facebook app.

The maximum number of test users that can be created is 2000.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users/

Comment: There isn’t a specific field for that as far as I can see, so the only way would be to paginate through the full list of test users.

Comment: well, that's a bummer